# Wear OS (Android Wear) wrong timestamps

Tags: android, timestamp, wear-os, android-sensors

I am trying to use the sensors in a few smartwatches running Wear OS. After sampling for a few seconds (it usually runs for 45 seconds but also up to a few minutes) the timestamps are wrong.

The timestamps jump several seconds or minutes in to the future, and then all the timestamps come at more or less the same time before or after this "break". So it ends up being a break with no timestamps and then many timestamps before returning to normal, and then it usually happens again.

The other values from the sensors (X,Y,Z) seem to be sampled at the correct time when I look at the data in a graph, but only if the X axis does not have the timestamps. It can happen after just a couple of seconds and can happen up to 6-7 times in that 45 second window.

Some info about the code:

- Sampling from Accelerometer, Gyro and Magnetometer (if available).
- Sampling is done in a service (foreground service).
- Partial wake lock is set when starting the sampling (Log.d shows that the wakelock is held throughout the 45 seconds).
- maxReportLatencyUs = 0 (tested with other numbers up to ten seconds)
- Sensor delay = Fastest (tested with Game)
- Same listener used for all sensors

There are usually 200 samples between the "breaks/jumps", but it can vary. They usually last for 2000, 4000 or 14000 ms.

I have only tested the app on 3 watches. 
The watches with this problem are:

- Huawei Watch 2 Classic (This is the worst one)
- Tag Heuer

The watch it does not happen on:

- Fossil Q Explorist Gen 3

This does not mean it would never happen on the Fossil watch, but I have not seen this happen there.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNALf.png) you can see the timestamps jumping so the data looks strange (accelerometer (X) on Y axis and timestamps on the X axis). When showing the data without the timestamps, it looks pretty much like it is supposed to and can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2tbt.png).

[This (timestamps on the Y axis (blue line). It was sampling for 6 min (360,000 ms))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2LOp.png) shows how the timestamps change over time. It seems to end at the right spot(almost.. (365,153 ms)), but on the way there, it seems to be a little bit slow and then catch up by jumping 14000 ms every 200 samples..? [This is a 3 min sampling with a Fossil Q Explorist Gen 3. This is what it should look like, the blue line is straight and laying behind the orange line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naVPc.png)

[This graph shows the difference between each timestamp (a[n+1] - a[n]). You can see exactly when it happens and how far the "jump" was.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0ze.png)

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?